# Typescript: union of several specific type value combination

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure how to summarize the question. Here's what I want to achieve:

I have some api handlers, createA, updateA, deleteA, createB, updateB, ..., and I want to export an object containing all handlers like:

```
const API = {
  A: {
    CREATE: createA,
    UPDATE: updateA,
    ...
  },
  B: {
    CREATE: createB,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Then get the handler with a function:

```js
type KeyAction = {
  key: "A" | "B" | "C";
  action: "CREATE" | "UPDATE" | "DELETE"
}
const getHandler = ({key, handler}: KeyAction) => {
  return API[key][action];
}
```

However, let's say B doesn't have a delete handler, how could I define the type correctly so that this `return API[key][action]` gives no ts errors?

I have tried

```js
type KeyAction = {
  key: "A" | "C";
  action: "CREATE" | "UPDATE" | "DELETE"
} | {
  key: "B";
  action: "CREATE" | "UPDATE"
}
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making the function generic?

```
const getHandler = <
  K extends keyof typeof API, 
  A extends keyof typeof API[K]
>({ key, action }: { key: K, action: A }) => {
  return API[key][action];
}

getHandler({ key: "A", action: "UPDATE" })
getHandler({ key: "B", action: "UPDATE" }) // Error
```

By defining the generic types `K` which represents a valid key of `API` and `A` which represents a key of `API[K]` we can silence the error in the function and also get an error when we call the function with invalid parameters.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=25&ssc=52&pln=17&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQQAoEk4F44G9h0QLm1zzgGEAlAUQQBVLCAiAQwCMQGAaYvAVSQBFa9OACYAzFzwBfSXABChHCTJUhjEACcApkxha5nYlODHgMAJ4AHLXADSW8whAwAlpAxE8AaweMEDOAAfOAYDAG5iJmc3CEYKajoA4IY%20QUSgkP5KABlKRJNgUEhYOABzLRgACSYIABMAGy0NDwAeYls4LQAPPTqoOB9zMAAzOAtrEcRUDjhiBE6erT6Bh0nxrUnkFABtWwBdYAA%20AAosFfMZqNd3KUVzwltL6MhCeakASgxDzzhtGABXDQQKY7QZ7bZXGJ7CKmcpVGoNJqne4hfxPa6xEKpIQBD7AOHVOqNDTIwaMAzomKMbHpD5wAD09LglA0GjAGiAA)